# How to use a variable in an aggregate query in mongoose/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a very basic Mongoose aggregate query

```
Transaction.aggregate().match({
    timestamp : {
        $gt : time_lower_bound,
        $lt : time_upper_bound
    }
}).group({
    _id : '$currencyFrom',
    count : {
        $sum : 1
    }
}).sort({
    count : -1
})
```

I wanted to make the _id dynamic. But i tried

```
var field = job.data.field;
Transaction.aggregate().match({
    timestamp : {
        $gt : time_lower_bound,
        $lt : time_upper_bound
    }
}).group({
    _id : '$' . field,
    count : {
        $sum : 1
    }
}).sort({
    count : -1
})
```

and it doesn't return the correct data, it returns

```
[ { _id: null, count: 473 } ]
```

so i'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses plus signs for concatenation, not periods.

Assuming `field` is a string like `currencyFrom`, replace

```
_id : '$' . field,
```

with

```
_id : '$' + field,
```